# VB.Net Outlook email creation works locally, fails on server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, outlook

When I run my project on my local machine it generates the Outlook email as expected, but if I upload all my code to our development server, it fails with this error message when run: [Exception: Cannot create ActiveX component.]
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.CreateObject(String ProgId, String ServerName) +509721
etc...

I know it's the Outlook that's failing because if I comment the sendmail() function, the rest of the page works fine. (it just doesn't create the email).
Local machine is Windows 7 with Outlook installed, Server is 2008R2 with no Office installed.  I have other pages that can write to Excel files, but they're using CrystalReports to handle it so I'm not sure if the server needs an Outlook dll registered, or if something else needs to happen.

Aspx page with a VB.Net codebehind.  My create email looks like:

```
    Dim OApp2 As Object, OMail2 As Object, signature2 As String
    OApp2 = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    OMail2 = OApp2.CreateItem(0)

    Dim alAttachList As New ArrayList(2)
    Dim iCounter As Integer

    alAttachList.Insert(0, "E:\Test\DEBUG CODE.txt")
    alAttachList.Insert(1, "\\RemoteServer\z\Test\Hello.bmp")

    sBody += "<br />" + "Attached are some files." + "<br />" + "They can also be found in: X:\Test\Test\Name  "
    With OMail2
        .Display()
    End With
    signature2 = OMail2.HTMLBody
    With OMail2
        .Subject = sSubject
        .To = sTo
        .CC = sCC
        .HTMLbody = sBody & "<br /><br />" & signature2

    End With

    Dim sBodyLen As Integer = Int(sBody.Length)
    Dim oAttachs2 As Interop.Outlook.Attachments = OMail2.Attachments
    Dim oAttach2 As Interop.Outlook.Attachment
    For iCounter = 0 To alAttachList.Count - 1
        oAttach2 = oAttachs2.Add(Source:=alAttachList(iCounter), DisplayName:=alAttachList(iCounter))
    Next

    OMail2.Display(True)

    OApp2 = Nothing
    OMail2 = Nothing
```

Comment: I don't know if this will help you, but i found this. The answer is at the bottom 
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1467460

Answer (score 1):

When you do something like:

```
OApp2 = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

You are using the Office.Interop libraries which are installed with MS Office (or the individual applications if you go that route)

You MUST install MS Office, or at least Outlook, on the server to use Office.Interop.  You might look into using MAPI instead of interop to send your emails. MAPI is part of .Net and does NOT require additional programs be installed on your server.

Comment: I thought that might have been the problem, but I was hoping that it wasn't.  It's an in house application so I want to generate and display the email for the users to be able to add notes to the pre-populated body before it gets sent to a client.  I'll check and see which is easier, installing Outlook, or re-writing to use MAPI (if I can display the message for editing before sending it).

Comment: @Dave If you want to show the email first, with MAPI, you will have to create your own editor. I'd tell you to use SENDMAIL but it has issues with certain versions of outlook not attaching your attachments. SENDMAIL also requires some type of email provider installed on the users machine too.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Outlook must be installed. Secondly, is your code running in a service (such as IIS)? No Office app (Outlook included) can be used from a service.

Comment: Yup, running on IIS.  The only reason I'm using Outlook is it's our default mail client and this is an in-house application.  I need the user to be the one to click the send button though, even if I give them a textbox to type a message in that will append to the email, they need final approval before it's sent so Outlook seemed the natural choice.  I guess not.

Comment: Your other choices are EWS (can be used in a service) or Redemption (wraps Extended MAPI; its RDO family of objects can be used in a service).